# how to find control inside dynamic user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added User-control in web page dynamically on page load using code below

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
Control ucDesignCatalogDetail =LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucCatalog.ascx"); 
ucDesignCatalogDetail.ID = "ucDesignCatalogDetail0"+i;
pnlDesignCatalog.Controls.Add(ucDesignCatalogDetail);
Label lblDesignID = ucDesignCatalogDetail.FindControl("lblDesignID") as Label;
lblDesignID.Text = dtCatalogDesignDetails.Rows[i]["DesignID"].ToString();
}
```

now on button click event i want to get text value of `lblDesignID` but it is giving this message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. what i have done is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(lblResultCount.Text) - 1; i++)
{
Control ucDesignCatalogDetail = (Control)pnlDesignCatalog.FindControl("ucDesignCatalogDetail0" + i);
Label lblDesignID = ucDesignCatalogDetail.FindControl("lblDesignID") as Label;
string strDesignID= lblDesignID.Text;
}
```

please guide

Comment: When are you executing `for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)` to add the controls. You need to do that after PostBack also, otherwise the controls are gone.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    ` {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
Control ucDesignCatalogDetail =LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucCatalog.ascx"); 
ucDesignCatalogDetail.ID = "ucDesignCatalogDetail0"+i;
pnlDesignCatalog.Controls.Add(ucDesignCatalogDetail);
Label lblDesignID = ucDesignCatalogDetail.FindControl("lblDesignID") as Label;
lblDesignID.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DesignID"].ToString();
}
            }

}

Comment: @Umair Please update your question instead of posting multiline code in an answer. It's not readable.

Comment: Remove the `Page.IsPostBack`